# Print Layout can not display correctly in Report viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, localreport

The report has been successfully generated, but I can not see its print layout. After I click the "Print Layout" button in Report Viewer, Error occurred:

> "An error occurred during local report processing, Parameter is not
>   valid."

Then i click the "Print Layout" button again, it's ok to go back to the normal layout...

Anyone can help?

I'm using vs2010 reportviewer winform, and in my .rdlc file ,I did not pass any parameters to the report except bind the business obj as DataSource.

**PS:**
After I delete the old rdlc file and create a new one, it works fine. Although the problem is gone, but i still don't know why!  If anyone who knows the reason tells me why, I'll be appreciated.

Comment: doe you have some more information. How is the report started from code? Inner exceptions? What have you tried already?

Comment: I created a .rdlc file and set it to reportviewer, then i create a business object as Data source of reportviewer's bindingsource. and refresh the report, it works fine. Next , i want to see the print layout, it gives me an big error.  i debugged it, got nothing except the error. still try to find a way.

Comment: And i drive the google and msdn crazy, but i don't get valuable info. if you want the code or rdlc file , let me know, Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a chart that was too wide for printing. Or rather, I forgot to put the report printing in landscape mode.

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve problem is: delete the old rdlc file and redesign an new rdlc.

Comment: I think i got it. The reason is that the width of Chart in your rdlc file is larger than an A4 paper width.